# How to give action on php pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have made two pages. I have used php form validation in my first page, i.e., form.php and I have to give action on second page i.e., data_ins.php. Please let me know how will it possible with my coding.

Here are my pages:

form.php

```
<?php   $fnameErr = $lnameErr = "";
$fname = $lname= ""; if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


if(empty($_POST['fname']))
{
    $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
}
else
{
    $fname= formVal($_POST['fname']);
}

 if(empty($_POST['lname']))
{
    $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
}
else
{
    $lname= formVal($_POST['lname']);
} }
function formVal($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripcslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}  

 ?> <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        First Name: 
        <input type="text" name="fname"> <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $fnameErr ?></span> <br>
        Last Name: 
        <input type="text" name="lname"> <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $lnameErr ?></span> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body> </html>
```

data_ins.php

```
<?php $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test_db");

$sql = "insert into records (FirstName, LastName) values ('$fname', $lname)";

if($result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    echo "Data Inserted Successfull";
}
else 

{
    echo "Invalid";
}
mysqli_error($conn); ?>
```

Comment: don't use form action SELF, instead link it to the other page and put your $_POST logic in there, or put your sql code from the second file into the first too.

Comment: possible using $_GET method on data_ins.php

Comment: your code is open for SQL injection, move data_ins.php code into form.php after validation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you may of made it harder than you needed to.

Here is what I'd do with the PHP side:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['fname']))
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['lname']))
        {

            // Add Database insert code here..

        } else {
            echo "Last name is required";
        }
    } else {
        echo "First name is required";
    }
}
```

As for the form, you don't need to add the PHP self (just add the method) like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps more so than your initial idea of doing it.

PLEASE NOTE: I haven't added the $data trim etc in but you'd add these in firstly where // do code note is.

Answer (score 0):

1.change your form like this

```
`<form method="POST" action="location of your data_ins.php">`
```

2.in your `data_ins.php` must have database config code or include it.

3.get your all form value in `data_ins.php` pass to `insert` query

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: than what about validation inside the form.php?

Comment: we can validate using js not php, before reach server side we want to validate right i thing this is the best approach else both in same file no need to external file

Answer (score 0):

Besides your code, your method (as question is not about it).

To execute other .php file you can use PHP statements:

- [require](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)
- [include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
- [include_once](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

In your case require should be the one to use, like: `require 'data_ins.php';` after validation.

Comment: if including the file is the solution, than y not TO ADD data_ins.php into same same. use only file instead of two

Comment: This is the answer to the question. How to give action on second page? You can statements... The OP did not say: make my form page awesome.